# SQL month sum and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in `table1` and `table2`.

`table 1` has columns `id` and `date` (the date is in format: 2028-2-22). In `table 2` I have `id` column and `month` column. I want to add this `month` column to the `date` column. The `id` rows relate to each other.

From this result I then wanted to left join on `id` to table 3.

```sql
Select table1*, table2*, dateadd((month(table1.date)),table2.month) as Datealtered
From table1
Left join table2
On table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: what is the datatype if the column date ? I hope it is not a varchar

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you are facing? Have you actually read the documentation for `dateadd`?

Comment: FYI it's backticks (`\``) for code markdown, not single smart quotes (`‘’`).

Comment: This question would be more clear if you would add some sample data and expected result. Please add this, but add it as text not as an image

Comment: I am guessing you need `dateadd(month, table2.Month, table1.date)` this is assuming that table2.Month is an int and table1.date is a date, datetime or datetime2. You could found that if you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thanks everyone, i actually did know that documentation above existed. This has been tremendously helpful! I changed the format to "dateadd(month, table2.Month, table1.date)" which has solved one of my issues. thanks